# Permission denied error for logged in user for Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am getting the following error when I try to run pig -help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1717)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1738)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)
```

Here is my configuration-
Apache Hadoop - 1.0.3
Apache Pig - 0.10.0
OS - Ubuntu 64-bit

User for whom the error is seen - "sumod" this is an admin level account. I have also created directory for him in the HDFS.
User for whom this error is NOT seen - "hadoop". I have created this user for hadoop jobs. He is not an admin user. But he belongs to "supergroup" on HDFS.
The paths are properly set for both the users.
I do not have to start hadoop while running "pig -help" command. I only want to make sure that Pig is installed properly.
I am following Apache doc and my understanding is that I do not have to be hadoop user to run Pig and I can be a general system user.

Why am I getting these errors? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permissions of the directory where the pigscript is placed.

Whenever a pigscript is executed, errors are logged in a log file, which is written in your present working directory.

Assume your pigscript is in dir1 and your pwd is dir2 and since you are executing as user sumod; sumod should have write permissions in dir2.

Answer (score 1):

I had seen the same exception error. The reason for me was that the user I was running pig did not have write permission on ${hadoop.tmp.dir}